# Why Na2CO3 is conjugate base

Tags: acid-base

The defintion of conjugate base is the base formed by removing 1 proton from acid. For example if $\ce{H2SO4}$ is acid then it dissociates as $\ce{H+ + HSO4-}$.

Now we consider $\ce{NaHCO3}$. If we remove one proton we are left with $\ce{NaCO3-}$. But we know $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is the conjugate base of $\ce{NaHCO3}$.But for that to happen we need to break $\ce{2 H+}$.I mean it becomes $\ce{2H+ + Na2CO3}$. But for conjugate base we need to remove $\ce{1 H+}$. That's why i am confused.

Comment: For better site experience, you can find useful [How can I format math expressions or chem. equations on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). ( Not to be applied to titles )

Comment: We ***did*** remove 1H+ from HCO3-.

Comment: First mistake : Removing one proton from $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is not possible. And it will not make $\ce{NaCO3^-}$. Second mistake : $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is not the conjugate base of $\ce{NaHCO3}$, because $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is not a base. It is made of a base, namely the ion $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ (plus two other $\ce{Na^+}$ ions), but it is not a base.

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{NaHCO3}$ and $\ce{Na2CO3}$ are not molecules, but ionic compounds consisting of $\ce{Na+},$ $\ce{HCO3-},$ respectively $\ce{CO3^2-}$ ions. . There is no ion like $\ce{NaCO3-}$, unless in extreme conditions like kryogenics or interstellar space.

$\ce{CO3^2-}$ is the conjugate base to $\ce{HCO3-}$, because of :

$$\ce{NaHCO3(s) ->[H2O] Na+(aq) + HCO3-(aq)}$$

$$\ce{HCO3-(aq) <=> H+(aq) + CO3^2-(aq)}$$

$\ce{NaHCO3}$ and $\ce{Na2CO3}$ are the respective conjugate acid/base pair only as secondary consideration, transforming the approach of involved ions/molecules into the approach of formal molecules and bystanding ions.

Comment: I don't understand how you wrote $NaHCO_3$ reacts to produce $H^{+}$ and $H{CO_{3}}^{-1}$ ions,where did $Na$ go?

Comment: You are right :-) I have somehow combined 2 correct reactions into 1 incorrect.