# Why is sodium carbonate a diacidic base?

Tags: acid-base

We know,the acidity of bases is defined by the number of replaceable $\ce{OH-}$ ions,or in case of oxides,it is the number of moles of $\ce{HCl}$ it reacts completely. But we know $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is diacidic. How is it determined?

Comment: Related: [Why Na2CO3 is conjugate base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/158720/101286)

Answer (score 1):

Carbonates, $\ce{CO^{2-}_3}$, formally derive from $\ce{H2CO3}$. You may postulate *two* deprotonations:

$$\ce{H2CO3 + H2O <=> HCO^-_3 + H3O+}$$

and

$$\ce{HCO^-_3 + H2O <=> H3O+ + CO^{2-}_3}$$

Thus, hydrogencarbonates are monobasic; and carbonates are dibasic.

---

However, note that $\ce{CO2}$ *gas* may solute *physically* in water (like, for example, oxygen may dissolve in water, too) without a chemical reaction which would create a chemical bond, or delete a chemical bond in the $\ce{CO2}$ molecule.  Instead, there is a chemical equilibrium between $\ce{CO2}$ and water and the hydrogencarbonate:

$$\ce{HCO^-_3 + H3O+ <=> H2O + CO2}$$

In contrast to sulfuric acid consisting of $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecules, those of carbonic acid ($\ce{H2CO3}$) decompose in the presence of water to yield $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: Does that mean we will have to make it react with water to ensure acidity?Like $\ce{Na2CO3}$ with $\ce{H2O}$?

Comment: «Monobasic», «dibasic», «tribasic» (e.g., $\ce{H3PO4}$); these are assignments on paper, the mentioned postulated about deprotonations possible *at all*.  If e.g., $\ce{HCO^-_3}$ *acts* like a base, or like an acid, however depends on the presence of a reaction partner which either is able to donate a proton, or is able to accept one proton. This then is a question of pKa of the reagents present. Even more so since water may be either acid, or base (amphoteric character), *and* that water undergoes some autoprotolysis ($\ce{2H2O <=> H3O+ + OH^-}$), too.